# Locales - why does dayjs behave like this?

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I need all dates to be assumed as locale en-gb (ie DD/MM/YYYY)

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import 'dayjs/locale/en-gb'
dayjs.locale('en-gb')

const date = '01/02/2000' // 1st Feb
console.log(dayjs(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')) // 02/01/2000 (wrong!)
```

Why is it assuming that the date is in usa format, when I have already set the locale?

Answer (score 0):

dayjs works correctly this is the international standard if you write `xx-xx-xxxx` or `xx/xx/xxxx` then the format is `m/d/y`. that means January 2, 2000

Answer (score 0):

Its because javascript reads the date in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format so what you have to do is change it to:

```js
console.log(dayjs(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('DD/MM/YYYY')) // 01/02/2000 (correct!)
```